# Add a JToken to a specific JsonPath in a JObject

Tags: c#, json

I have a JObject that looks like this..

```
{
    "address": [
        {
            "addressLine1": "123",
            "addressLine2": "124"
        },
        {
            "addressLine1": "123",
            "addressLine2": "144"
        }
    ]
}
```

for JsonPath `address[2]`, I want to add the following JObject to the `address` array.

```
{
     "addressLine1": "123",
     "addressLine2": "144"
}
```

I want to do something like json.TryAdd(jsonPath, value);

If there was an object at index `2` i would have easily done

```
var token = json.SelectToken(jsonPath);
if (token != null && token .Type != JTokenType.Null)
{
      token .Replace(value);
}
```

but since that index does not exist I'll get null as the value of `token`

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm, Exemple of add, insert remove etc. with Json.net

Comment: What do you want to do if indext doest not exist? (Yet you don't have item to replace)

Comment: @SelimYıldız in cases like this, I have to add the JToken at that index.

Comment: You can not insert that index since index does not exist. Just add new item as a last item of array, does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we mentioned on comment section, you can not add/replace item to index if index does not exist. In that case you need to add item as a new member of `JArray` instead, or you can use [`Insert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Insert.htm) to add item at the specified index :

```
JObject value = new JObject();
value.Add("addressLine1", "123");
value.Add("addressLine2", "144");

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
int index = 2;
JToken token = o.SelectToken("address[" + index + "]");
if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
{
    token.Replace(value);
}
else //If index does not exist than add to Array
{
    JArray jsonArray = (JArray)o["address"];
    jsonArray.Add(value);
    //jsonArray.Insert(index, value); Or you can use Insert

}
```